# How to attach screenshot to Extent Report in java selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, extentreports

I am trying to attach screenshot for failed testcases from my path to Extent Report but somehow i am not able to attach into it.

I have tried my possible solution but it fails .
I have used extent report version 3

here is mine full code in separate extenreport class :

```
    package com.qa.ExtentReportListener;


    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.testng.IReporter;
    import org.testng.IResultMap;
    import org.testng.ISuite;
    import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
    import org.testng.ITestContext;
    import org.testng.ITestResult;
    import org.testng.Reporter;
    import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

    import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.ChartLocation;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.configuration.Theme;
    import com.crm.qa.util.TestUtil;

    public class ExtentTestNGIReporterListener implements IReporter {

        private static final String OUTPUT_FOLDER = "test-output/";
        private static final String FILE_NAME = "Extent.html";

        private ExtentReports extent;
        private ExtentTest test;

        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
            init();

            for (ISuite suite : suites) {
                Map<String, ISuiteResult> result = suite.getResults();

                for (ISuiteResult r : result.values()) {
                    ITestContext context = r.getTestContext();

                    buildTestNodes(context.getFailedTests(), Status.FAIL);
                    buildTestNodes(context.getSkippedTests(), Status.SKIP);
                    buildTestNodes(context.getPassedTests(), Status.PASS);

                }
            }

            for (String s : Reporter.getOutput()) {
                extent.setTestRunnerOutput(s);
            }

            extent.flush();
        }

        private void init() {
            ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(OUTPUT_FOLDER + FILE_NAME);
            htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("ExtentReports - Created by TestNG Listener");
            htmlReporter.config().setReportName("ExtentReports - Created by TestNG Listener");
            htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
            htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);

            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
            extent.setReportUsesManualConfiguration(true);
        }

        private void buildTestNodes(IResultMap tests, Status status) {


            if (tests.size() > 0) {
                for (ITestResult result : tests.getAllResults()) {
                    test = extent.createTest(result.getMethod().getMethodName());

                    for (String group : result.getMethod().getGroups())
                        test.assignCategory(group);

                    if (result.getThrowable() != null) {
                        test.log(status, result.getThrowable());
                    }
                    else {
                        test.log(status, "Test " + status.toString().toLowerCase() + "ed");
                    }

                    test.getModel().setStartTime(getTime(result.getStartMillis()));
                    test.getModel().setEndTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));
                }
            }
        }

        public void down(ITestResult result) throws IOException{


            if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE){
                test.log(Status.FAIL, "TEST CASE FAILED IS "+result.getName()); //to add name in extent report
                test.log(Status.FAIL, "TEST CASE FAILED IS "+result.getThrowable()); //to add error/exception in extent report

                String screenshotPath = TestUtil.takeScreenshotAtEndOfTest();
                test.fail("Test Case failed check screenshot below"+test.addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath));
                //extentTest.log(Status.FAIL, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath).build()); //to add screenshot in extent report
                //extentTest.fail("details").addScreenCaptureFromPath(screenshotPath);
            }
            else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SKIP){
                test.log(Status.SKIP, "Test Case SKIPPED IS " + result.getName());
            }
            else if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS){
                test.log(Status.PASS, "Test Case PASSED IS " + result.getName());

            }
        extent.flush();
        }

        private Date getTime(long millis) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(millis);
            return calendar.getTime();      
        }
    }
```

here is my util class which contain screenshot method:

```
public static String takeScreenshotAtEndOfTest() throws IOException {
    String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot)driver;
    File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String destination = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/screenshots/" +  dateName
            + ".png";
    File finalDestination = new File(destination);
    FileHandler.copy(source, finalDestination);
    return destination;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in after method

```java
if(result.getStatus()==result.FAILURE || result.getStatus()==result.SKIP) {
            String screenshotPath = util.captureScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
            result.setAttribute("screenshotPath", screenshotPath); //sets the value the variable/attribute screenshotPath as the path of the sceenshot
        }
```

and add below code in buildtestnodes

```java
    if(result.getStatus()==result.FAILURE || result.getStatus()==result.SKIP) {
                        String screenshotPath=(String) 
     result.getAttribute("screenshotPath");
                        test.log(status, test.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want take screen shots for failed test cases with test class name use below code segment.

[image: click here]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Extent Report already provide the utility to take the screenshot .Please refer the below link:

https://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#automatic-screenshot-management

also find the snapshot and code for same:

```
 ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter("extent.html");
htmlReporter.config().setAutoCreateRelativePathMedia(true);

test1.fail("details", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("1.png").build());
test2.fail("details", MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath("2.png").build());
```

[how to take Screenshot using extent report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul1Og.png)

Comment: It's better to provide process description instead of just links.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
logger.log(Status.FAIL, logger.addScreenCaptureFromPath("YOUR PATH"));
```

UPDATE :
If this doesn't work, just cast the inner logger with markup.
import com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.Markup;

Comment: Getting error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest cannot be cast to com.aventstack.extentreports.markuputils.Markup

Comment: take the object of ExtentTest, then use that object to add screenshot in this manner - child.addScreenCaptureFromPath(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/screenshots/" + name);

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.helper;

    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    import com.aventstack.extentreports.AnalysisStrategy;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.MediaEntityBuilder;
    import com.aventstack.extentreports.Status;

    import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentSparkReporter;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;

    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
    import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;
    import org.testng.IResultMap;
    import org.testng.ITest;
    import org.testng.ITestContext;
    import org.testng.ITestResult;
    import org.testng.Reporter;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
    import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;







    public class TestingEdgeDriver {
        ExtentReports extent;
        ExtentTest test;
        WebDriver driver;
        ExtentTest Parent;
        ExtentTest child1,child;
        
        @BeforeMethod
        public void setup(){
            
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH-mm-ss"); 
            String destDir = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            ExtentSparkReporter esp=new ExtentSparkReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/ExtentReport/ExtentReports_"+destDir+"/SwarupExtentReport.html");
            extent=new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(esp);
            extent.setAnalysisStrategy(AnalysisStrategy.SUITE);
        }
        
        @Test (testName="Chrome browser Testing")public void chromeBrowser() throws IOException{
            /*extent.attachReporter(spark);
            extent.createTest("chromeBrowser").log(Status.PASS  , "This is logging event for the setup and it is passed");
            extent.flush();*/
            Parent=extent.createTest("CMO");
            child1=Parent.createNode("Test1");
            child=child1.createNode("Chrome browser Testing");
            
            System.out.println("The tread value for Chrome browser is "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\chromedriver_win32 (2)\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            child.log(Status.PASS, "Chrome browser has opened",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(capture(driver)).build());
            driver.get("https://www.icicibank.com");
            
            child.log(Status.PASS,"Expected was its should open the bank website",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(capture(driver)).build());
            
            child.log(Status.PASS, "Need to open the URL "+" http://www.icicibank.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            child.log(Status.PASS, "Test Case is passed",MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(capture(driver)).build());
            
            
            
        }
        
        @AfterMethod
        public void getResult(ITestResult result){
            if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS){
                child.log(Status.PASS, "Test case is passed "+result.getStatus()+" "+result.getTestClass()+"  "+result.getName());
                child.log(Status.PASS, "Test case is passed "+result.getTestName());
                
            }
            if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE){
                child.log(Status.FAIL, "Test case is failed at below location "+result.getThrowable());
            }
            extent.flush();
        }
        
        
        /*@Test public void operaTesting(){
            System.out.println("The tread value for Opera browser is "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
            System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver","E:\\operadriver_win32\\operadriver_win32\\operadriver.exe");
            Reporter.log("opera driver has been set",true);
            driver=new OperaDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in");
        }
        @Test public void FirefoxTesting(){
            System.out.println("The tread value for Firefox browser is "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\gecodriver\\geckodriver-v0.29.0-win32\\geckodriver.exe");
            Reporter.log("Gecko Driver has been set",true);
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            Reporter.log("firefox driver has been initialsed",true);
            driver.get("https://www.primevideo.com/");
        }
        @Test public void InternetExplorerTesting(){
            System.out.println("The tread value for IE browser is "+ Thread.currentThread().getId());
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","E:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
            Reporter.log("IE driver has been set",true);
            driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https://www.hotstar.com/in");
        }*/
        
        public static String captureBase64(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
            String encodedBase64 = null;
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File Dest = new File("src/../BStackImages/" + System.currentTimeMillis()
            + ".png");
            String errflpath = Dest.getAbsolutePath();
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, Dest);
             
            try {
                
                fileInputStream =new FileInputStream(Dest);
                byte[] bytes =new byte[(int)Dest.length()];
                fileInputStream.read(bytes);
                encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));

            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "data:image/png;base64,"+encodedBase64;
            
            
            }
        
        public static String capture(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
            
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            File Dest = new File("src/../BStackImages/" + System.currentTimeMillis()
            + ".png");
            String errflpath = Dest.getAbsolutePath();
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, Dest);
            return errflpath;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Use this following example is in Java

```
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

   driver.get("http://www.google.com/");

        // Store the screenshot in current project dir.
        String screenShot = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\Artifacts\\FileName.png";

        // Call Webdriver to click the screenshot.
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

        // Save the screenshot.
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(screenShot));
```

Comment: Use this util class it contain screenshot method.

Comment: this is not the logic anyway, this can be just used for taking screenshot not more than that but  I want the failed test case screenshot in Extent Report